# GMA 6300 in asus eeepc x101ch stuck at 800x600

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, resolution, asus

I've read that this card is unsupported at the moment and i can wait with ubuntu 2D. 
What i can't stand is working in 800x600 resolution. Any ideas?

I'm running Precise Beta 2 on a Asus eeepc x101ch

Thank u !!!

Comment: I am having this exact same problem with Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: check my answer to the other identical question

Comment: I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` in my `Acer D270` netbook. It also has `GMA 3600` but for me the resolution is perfect `1024X600`.

Answer (score 1):

You should correct your question to "GMA 3600". I'm not sure how to get it working in Ubuntu but I've heard it works properly in [Meego](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953734). Maybe someone here can suggest a way of pulling the driver from there.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. So I tried running Quantal (12.10) and the resolution was OK. So I went back on 12.04 and upgraded the kernel. It now works perfectly.

[See here for the kernel upgrade.](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/how-to-install-kernel-342-under-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I am using `Ubuntu 12.04` in my `Acer D270` netbook. It also has `GMA 3600` but for me the resolution is perfect `1024X600`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution in this link - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11976680&postcount=97 has solved my resolution issue.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.